# If the word "кречет" were a verb, what would its initial form look like?

Tags: глаголы

I think this is a very interesting linguistic problem.

A teacher once proposed the following to her class: "Children, let's imagine for a minute that the Russian word "кречет" is a verb. What would its infinitive be?"

(Однажды учительница предложила классу задание: «Дети, давайте пофантазируем и всего на одну минутку представим себе, что слово "кречет" — это глагол. Какова его начальная форма (инфинитив)?»

[I *could* provide the source for this question, but I consider it a spoiler because it kind of contains the answer.]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It would be either **крекать* (by analogy with *кликать/кличет, тыкать/тычет, скакать/скачет* or **кретать* (by analogy with *метать/мечет, рокотать/рокочет, прятать/прячет*).

[*Кретать*](https://dic.academic.ru/dic.nsf/enc2p/259082), by the way, is attested in Dahl's dictionary, but its actual declension pattern is not provided (it might as well have been **кретает*). There also exists apparently related Serbo-Croatian word [*кретати*](https://en.m.wiktionary.org/wiki/%D0%BA%D1%80%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B8), which gives *креће* in the present third person singular.

Comment: Thanks, What about "кречь" or "кречать"?

Comment: @Alexander: they would have given _*кречёт, *крежёт, *крекает, *кречит_ or _*кречает_. Compare _сечь, беречь, обречь, кричать, изучать_.

Comment: In Serbian, "кретати" means "to move", and the conjugation paradigm is "кречем" (transcribed in Russian).

Answer (score 4):

Прямым аналогом было бы слово "мечет",
форма глагола "метать".